# "WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified" - I've tried to follow advice online and on videos but I just can't seem to make it work

Tags: python, windows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TngsW.jpg)This is the error message, I keep going to environment variables but I don't know how to add python where and just typing it at the beginning is not working.
Please help.
I would love to learn python and become proficient.
Following Corey Schae

> [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified [cmd:
> ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u', '']] [dir: C:\Program Files\Sublime
> Text] [path:
> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
> Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program
> Files\Polyspace\R2021a\runtime\win64;C:\Program
> Files\Polyspace\R2021a\bin;C:\Users\money\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\money\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Users\money\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program
> Files\Sublime Text
> 3;"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
> Corporation\NVI";]

Comment: I'm trying to run a simple 
print ("hello")

Comment: how do you run it ? it seems you run Windows but it tries to use path `/usr/local/bin/python3` which works only in Linux (and maybe in MacOS)

Comment: maybe run it in normal way - in console/cmd.exe `python script.py`. OR use other Editor or IDE - with `Sublime Text` you would have to change something in settings to run it in Windows. OR search information how to change settings in `Sublime Text` because all problem it `Sublime Text`

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail, Mr. Furas or advice some videos/instructional pages to me which I can follow step-by-step?
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I don't use `Sublime Text` but I use `Linux` and I know that `/usr/local/bin/python3` (which shows error) is for Linux. You should search information how to change settings in `Sublime Text`

Comment: using Google `"sublime text change python path windows"` I found forum for `Sublime Text` and maybe you should search on this forum - i.e. [How to link Sublime Text 3 Build system to Python 3.9 Using Windows 10 - Technical Support - Sublime Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-link-sublime-text-3-build-system-to-python-3-9-using-windows-10/54993)